# UCase for each statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a string that may contain numbers to UpperCase using `UCase`. When I used a line like that

```
For Each vLetter In UCase(lName)
```

I encountered an error when the lName variable equals to "Yasser51" as an example. How can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `For Each` like this. `For Each` can only iterate over a collection or an array. A `String` is neither.

One option to loop character-by-character is `Mid$` and a regular `For` loop. (*Though it's still unclear what you're actually trying to do and if a loop is even required*):

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim lName As String
    lName = "Yasser51"
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(lName)
        Dim letter As String
        letter = Mid$(UCase(lName), i, 1)
        
        Debug.Print letter
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to check if all the letters are strings only (not numbers or spaces or special characters)

Comment: Gotcha. I figured you intended to loop but I guess that is confirmation :-)

Comment: Is there an easier way to check for string such as the function `IsNumeric` that checks for numbers?

Comment: I am trying to check if all the letters are strings only (not numbers or spaces or special characters). Just to make sure the entry are letters from A-Z

Comment: You can probably use `Asc`, or regex.

Comment: Try a condition such as `Asc(LCase(letter)) >= Asc("a") And Asc(LCase(letter)) <= Asc("z")` or with regex `letter Like "[a-zA-Z]"`

Comment: FYI @YasserKhalil added a late post how to iterate "Yasser51" via a ► **`Byte`** array.

Answer (score 3):

To convert to upper case you simply use `UCase`. If you want to iterate then see @BigBen's answer.

```
Dim sName as String
Dim sUpper as String

sName = "Yasser51"
sUpper = UCase(sName)
```

Comment: My suggestion was actually to *not* use `For Each`. OP still wants to iterate it seems.

Comment: @BigBen I see. Just saw your answer.

Comment: @BigBen I didn't get the impression the OP _wanted_ to iterate.  However, both answers are good and cover the bases either way.

Comment: Hard to say, he may have just been trying to iterate through each character of the string, not multiple strings. Such is the problem with not getting enough context in the OP.

Comment: I agree with all the comments above on a re-read of the question. Not enough context for sure.

Answer (score 3):

**Addendum**

As mentioned a string is neither a *collection* nor an *array*,
*however* you can assign a string to a ► **`Byte`** array that can be iterated easily via a `For Each` loop.

Note that the **`Byte`** array always contains pairs of bytes with numeric values;
so for example **digits** `0-9` are shown as numeric `Asc` values between `48-57` (together with value `0` as further companion value), similar for usual letter characters `A-Z` and `a-z`.

```
Sub IterateByte()
Dim s   As String: s = "Yasser51"
Dim b() As Byte: b = s

Debug.Print " i", "Asc Value ", "ch| IsDigit" & vbNewLine & String(50, "-")

Dim i As Long, ch As String, vNum As Variant
For Each vNum In b
    ch = Chr(vNum)
    If vNum Then Debug.Print i, "Asc " & vNum, ch & " | " & (ch Like "#")
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

**Example result in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
' i            Asc Value     Ch| IsDigit
'--------------------------------------------------
' 0            Asc 89        Y | False
' 2            Asc 97        a | False
' 4            Asc 115       s | False
' 6            Asc 115       s | False
' 8            Asc 101       e | False
' 10           Asc 114       r | False
' 12           Asc 53        5 | True
' 14           Asc 49        1 | True
```

Comment: FYI You might as well be interested in a tricky way to get a digits array at [Divide numbers into unique sorted digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540928/divide-numbers-into-unique-sorted-digits-displayed-in-a-label-on-a-userform/63546848#63546848
) - @YasserKhalil