# Divide numbers into unique sorted digits displayed in a label on a userform

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, duplicates

I want to divide numbers into unique sorted digits.
For example, the number can be 127425 and I would like 12457 as the result, meaning sorted and duplicate removed. I think the best is to explain with example:

```
+---------+--------+
| Number  | Result |
+---------+--------+
| 127425  | 12457  |
+---------+--------+
| 2784425 | 24578  |
+---------+--------+
| 121     | 12     |
+---------+--------+
| 22222   | 2      |
+---------+--------+
| 9271    | 1279   |
+---------+--------+
```

The longest result can be only 123456789.

I don't think we need an array for that (no delimiter), but the use of substring could probably do the job. I just don't know where to begin, hence no code.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What about 0 digit? Just forgotten or missing on purpose?

Comment: No zero, only 9 digits possible or less in the result. The initial number can have 20 digits or more (even if it is unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function RemoveDuplSort(x As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr As Variant, temp As String
  'Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary 'in case of reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime,
                                        'un-comment this line and comment the next one:
  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To Len(x)
    dict(Mid(x, i, 1)) = 1
  Next i
  arr = dict.Keys
      For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(i)
                arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
  RemoveDuplSort = Join(arr, "")
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testRemoveDuplSort()
  Dim x As String
  x = "2784425" 'x = myLabel.Caption
  Debug.Print RemoveDuplSort(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: Work like a charm and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Nice. FYI might be interested in alternative via tricky Byte array as well as FilterXML + Filter function @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. Yes, the byte array (using `StrConv(x, vbFromUnicode)`) should be a good alternative instead of iteration using Mid, but the iteration is anyhow, necessary for the `Dictionary` loading. Is it a way to filter it directly? About FilterXML, I could see its implementation mostly in your answers... :) It did not look complicated, but I do not have the habit to use it from reflex. When I will find some time, I promised to myself to play a little with XML approach...

Comment: Firstly, I like your answer. ... Secondly, as I'm always trying to explore further approaches enriching my own knowledge, my answer below (workable vers. 2013+) does not only demonstrate how to transform a string to a digits array (originally `Byte` type), but also to get *uniques* via `FilterXML` instead of a *dictionary*.  @FaneDuru

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative to the newer dynamic array functions**

Loving the above nice solutions it's always a challenge to think over additional approaches (via `Byte` array, `Filter()` and `FilterXML()` function):

```
Function UniqueDigits(ByVal txt) As String
    Dim by() As Byte: by = txt
    Dim digits: digits = Array(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 0) ' equalling Asc values
'a) create 1-based 1-dim array with digit positions
    Dim tmp: tmp = Filter(Application.Match(by, digits, 0), 11, False)
'b) get uniques
    tmp = Uniques(tmp)
'c) sort it (don't execute before getting uniques)
    BubbleSort tmp
'd) return function result
    UniqueDigits = Join(tmp, "")
End Function
```

```
Function Uniques(arr)
'Note: using FilterXML() available since vers. 2013+
    Dim content As String       ' replacing "10" referring to zero indexed as 10th digit
    content = Replace("<t><s>" & Join(arr, "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "10", "0")
    arr = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(content, "//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")
    Uniques = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Function
```

```
Sub BubbleSort(arr)
    Dim cnt As Long, nxt As Long, temp
    For cnt = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For nxt = cnt + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(cnt) > arr(nxt) Then
                temp = arr(cnt)
                arr(cnt) = arr(nxt)
                arr(nxt) = temp
            End If
        Next nxt
    Next cnt
End Sub
```

---

**Further hints :-) tl;dr**

...explaining

a) how to transform a string to a digits array,
b) how to get uniques via FilterXML instead of a dictionary
c) (executing BubbleSort needs no further explanation).

**`ad a)` the tricky way to get a pure digits array**
Transforming a string of digits into an array of single characters may need some explanation.

1. A string (here `txt`) can assigned easily to a byte array via `Dim by() As Byte: by = txt`. (Note that classical characters would be represented in a byte array by a *pair* of `Asc` values, where the second value mostly
   is `0`; so digit `1` is represented by 49 and 0, `2` by 50 and 0 up to `9` by 57 and 0).

Digits are defined in a 1-based `Asc` value array from `1`~>49  to `9`~>57, followed by the 10th item `0`~>48 and
eventually the `Asc` value `0` as 11th item related to each second byte pair.

```
Dim digits: digits = Array(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 0) ' equalling Asc values
```

2. Usually the `Match()` function searches for a *specified item* in order to get its relative position within an array (here `digits`) and would be executed by the following [syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a): ``.

> MATCH(*lookup_value*, lookup_array, [match_type])
> where the *lookup_value* argument can be a value (number, text, or logical value) or a cell reference to a number, text, or logical value.

An *undocumented* feature is that instead searching e.g. `2` in the lookup_array `digits` via
`Application.Match(2, digits,0)` you can use the **byte array** as first argument serving as 1-based array pattern where VBA replaces the current `Asc` values by their **position** found within the digits array.

```
Application.Match(by, digits, 0)
```

Finally a *negative filtering* removes the companion `Asc 0` values (`11` plus argument `False`) via

```
Dim tmp: tmp = Filter(Application.Match(by, digits, 0), 11, False)
```

**`ad b)` get uniques via FilterXML**

Help reference for the [`WorksheetFunction.FilterXML` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.filterxml) demands two string parameters

> FilterXML(XMLContentString, XPathQueryString)

The first argument doesn't reference a file, but needs a valid ("wellformed") XML text string starting with a root node (DocumentElement) which is roughly comparable to a html structure starting with the enclosing pair of `<html>...</html>` tags.

So a wellformed **content string** representing e.g. number `121` could be:

```
<t>
    <s>1</s>
    <s>2</s>
    <s>1</s>
</t>
```

The second argument (limited to 1024 characters) must be a valid **XPath query string** like the following find non-duplicates

```
"//s[not(preceding::*=.)]"
```

where the double slash `//` allows to find `s` nodes at any hierarchy level and under the condition that it is not
preceded by any nodes `*` with the same value content `=.`

**Recommended readings**

@RonRosenfeld is a pioneer author of numerous answers covering the `FilterXML` method, such as e.g. [Split string cell...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula/25316426#25316426).

@JvDV wrote a nearly encyclopaedic overview at [Extract substrings from string using FilterXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697).

Comment: That sounds also quite interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Another VBA routine to sort the unique elements of a cell, using an `ArrayList`:

```
Option Explicit
Function sortUniqueCellContents(S As String) As String
    Dim arr As Object, I As Long, ch As String * 1
    
Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For I = 1 To Len(S)
    ch = Mid(S, I)
    If Not arr.contains(ch) Then arr.Add ch
Next I

arr.Sort
sortUniqueCellContents = Join(arr.toarray, "")

End Function
```

Comment: Good one, but I decided to use the answer from FaneDuru. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a version of Excel that supports Dynaaic Arrays, then try this (for input in `A2`)

```
=CONCAT(SORT(UNIQUE(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2),1,1,1),1))))
```

How it works

1. `SEQUENCE(LEN(A27),1,1,1)` returns an array of numbers *1 .. the length of the input string*
2. `MID(A2, ... ,1))` uses that array to return a Spill range of the individual characters in the input string
3. `UNIQUE(` reduces that to a range of unique characters only
4. `SORT` sorts that range
5. `CONCAT` concatenates that range into a single string

Gearing off that to build a VBA function

```
Function UniqueDigits(s As String) As String
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        UniqueDigits = Join(.Sort(.Unique(Split(Left$(StrConv(s, 64), Len(s) * 2 - 1), Chr(0)), 1), , , 1), "")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting, but not what I was looking for. I will try to remember this anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is in cell A3, then this one will return a string of unique numbers.
=CONCAT(SORT(UNIQUE(MID(A3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A3))),1))))

Comment: ahh, wait I did read the header that said the number was in a label in a userform, did not check how to access these..maybe you can still figure out some way to use this.

Comment: Exact, but I could put the number in a cell, use your formula and get the result back to my form... Not exactly what I wanted. Thanks.